# how to fill the items in combo box from database based on the selected item of another combo box

Tags: javascript, php, html, combobox

When the user selected one of the items in grade_level combobox, the section combobox will automatically fill the sectionName from database. Each grade_level has their own table in database and it's kinda hard because I know javascript has something to do with this. Can you help me to get the selected item and get the data from database?

```
<script>
    function makeEnable(value){
        document.getElementById("section").disabled = (value=="KINDER 1"||value=="KINDER 2");
    }
</script>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Grade Level:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="grade_level" onChange="makeEnable(this.value)" id="grade_level" class="span2" required>
            <option></option>
            <option value="KINDER 1">KINDER 1</option>
            <option value="KINDER 2">KINDER 2</option>
            <option value="GRADE 1">GRADE 1</option>
            <option value="GRADE 2">GRADE 2</option>
            <option value="GRADE 3">GRADE 3</option>
            <option value="GRADE 4">GRADE 4</option>
            <option value="GRADE 5">GRADE 5</option>
            <option value="GRADE 6">GRADE 6</option>
            <option value="GRADE 7">GRADE 7</option>
            <option value="GRADE 8">GRADE 8</option>
            <option value="GRADE 9">GRADE 9</option>
            <option value="GRADE 10">GRADE 10</option>
            <option value="GRADE 11">GRADE 11</option>
            <option value="GRADE 12">GRADE 12</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Section:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="section" id="section" required class="span2">
            <option></option>
            <?php
                $query=mysql_query("select * from grade_one") or die(mysql_error());
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['sectionName']; ?>"><?php echo $row['sectionName']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> There must some sort of mapping between `select` value and table name.

Value of `selected` option must have some relation with the table name, if that is not possible then you must have an array of objects which will be having relation of the both(`[{'val':'abc pqr', table_name: 'abc_pqr_xyz'}]`). This way you can determine which table to be used while making query.

Second select box will be empty initially, once `onchange` is fired on first select input, get the value which is mapped with the table name, and retrieve values from specific table.

I would suggest you to go through `ajax` to achieve this. Could be achieved without `ajax` too which is not recommended.

Comment: There's a good library/example here: http://plugins.krajee.com/dependent-dropdown/demo. It demonstrates what Rayon talks about.